# How can I find the category by giving search key matches a item under a category in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have some categories and each category has a list of items like below
[image]

I want to be able to find the category by giving the item name, for example enter "Apple Pie", it should return Dessert.
I have tried VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, LOOKUP, XLOOKUP and Query, but still cannot work out the formula...
Is it possible?

Comment: There is no item like "Pizza" in your table nor "Food" category. Where do you want to retrieve this data from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=tocol(index(if(A2:C=F1,A1:C1,)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it seems to work. But I am trying to figure out how it works. Especially this part `A2:C=F1` in `if(A2:C=F1,A1:C1,)`... I could not find any example. If just put `if(A2:C=F1,A1:C1,)` in a cell i just get a value error.

Comment: Try `index(if(A2:C=F1,A1:C1,))` and you should see the backend logic now

Comment: Try: `=unique(tocol(index(if(regexmatch(A2:C,"(?i)"&F1),A1:C1,)),1))` Also this will return both Fruit & Dessert if you search for `Apple` since it now matches in multiple column(s). sorry dont have any documentation of sorts to share!

Comment: Thank you. I just realized I asked the wrong question... I posted another one. Could you take a look for me? Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/q/75918492/452486