# How to return category if one of its item partically matches entered value?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to enter an item name, and if any word matches one of items in each category, return that category.
For example, enter "Bubble Tea", "Tea" matches one item in "Drink" category.
The enter value is actually in another sheet, I just put it together for demostrating. There is a sheet that is specifically for categories, and categories could added/removed.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
=INDEX(TOCOL(IF(SEARCH(A2:C,F1),A1:C1),3),1)
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my question, and based on your answer, I tried `INDEX(TOCOL(IF(SEARCH($A$5:$Z,$B$1),$A$4:$Z$4),3),1)`, it works. However, if I enter `Watermelon`, it also returns `Dessert`. I have to use `$A$5:$Z` and `$A$4:$Z$4` for future cateogires expansion. How can I fix it?

Comment: best practice is to ask only one question per post. Please create a new post with your new question.

Comment: I worked out this: `=IFERROR(INDEX(TOROW(IF(IF($A$5:$C$8<>"",SEARCH($A$5:$C$8,$B$1)),$A$4:$C$4,),3),1), "")`. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
=unique(tocol(let(Σ,{split(F1," ")},
   reduce(iferror(index(sequence(1,columns(Categories!A1:Z1))/0)),sequence(counta(Σ)),lambda(a,c,{a;index(if(regexmatch(Categories!A2:Z,"(?i)"&index(Σ,c)),Categories!A1:Z1,))}))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Omg... this is beyond my scope of knowledge of spreadsheet....LOL

Comment: Also inversely does search item `tea` need to match `bubble tea` in Column_C?!

Comment: No does not need it...good enough. Thank you so much..

Comment: Actually, I just found an issue, because my categories could be extended, looks like the formula has hardcoded to 3... 
The value entered value in my spreadsheet is actually in another sheet, there is a sheet specifically for categories. The example is just for covenient.

Comment: replace the `A1:C1` part in the above formula to your category header range

Comment: I tried `=unique(tocol(let(Σ,{B1,split(B1," ")},reduce(iferror(index(sequence(1,counta(Categories!A1:Z1))/0)),sequence(counta(Σ)),lambda(a,c,{a;index(if(Categories!A2:Z=index(Σ,c),Categories!A1:Z1,))}))),1))`, I got `In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.
`. I found `A2:Z` needs values cannot be blank. `A2:C` works. But I want to use the same formula without have to update it when adding new categories and items. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you try the above updated answer...

Comment: Yes! Finally, everything works now! you are truly expert! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
=let(
categories,A1:C1,
items,A2:C3,
searchitem,F1,
filter(categories,bycol(regexmatch(lower(searchitem),lower(items)),lambda(col,or(col)))))
```

This will return as many categories as are appropriate (e.g. 'Apple Pie' returns 'dessert' and 'fruit'), and is also case-insensitive for the matches.

Comment: it seems like `ArrayFormula` isn't necessary here.

Comment: Ah yes - it's a hangover I forgot to remove from where I was building the formula prior to encapsulating the REGEXMATCH within FILTER, at which point the ARRAYFORMULA was no longer required... I've removed it now.